# TypeScript - How to splite react context with dispatch actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am currently trying to build simple to-dos app with `createContext` and `useReducer` but I'm currently stuck with TypeScript part and can't figure out how to fix this

```
Argument of type '(state: todos[], action: action) => todos[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'action'.
  Type '(state: todos[], action: action) => todos[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: "delet"; id: string; }': type, id  TS2345

     9 | 
    10 | export const AppContext = createContext<todos[]>([]);
  > 11 | export const AppReducerContext = createContext<action>(Reducer);
       |                                                        ^
    12 | 
    13 | const initData: todos[] = [];
    14 |
```

Context file :

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer, { action } from "./Reducer";

export interface todos {
  id: string;
  task: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

export const AppContext = createContext<todos[]>([]);
export const AppReducerContext = createContext<action>(Reducer);

const initData: todos[] = [];

export const AppContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initData);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={state}>
      <AppReducerContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AppReducerContext.Provider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

reducer file

```
import { todos } from "./Context";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

export type action =
  | { type: "add"; task: string }
  | { type: "delet"; id: string };

const Reducer = (state: todos[], action: action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      return [...state, { id: uuid(), task: action.task, completed: false }];
    case "delet":
      return state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer;
```

so how can i configure dispatch with `createContext()` with `dispatch` actions

here is the reference code I'm trying to convert to typescript :- https://github.com/Colt/todos-context-usereducer/blob/4-split-contexts/src/context/todos.context.js

Comment: What is "splite" supposed to mean?

Answer (score -1):

nvm i figur it out

```
export const AppReducerContext = createContext<React.Dispatch<action>>(
  () => {}
);
```

just use this if u want to splite the context